# Problema con limpieza de buffer en C

Tags: c

recien estaba repasando `C` y estaba haciendo un programa, tenia el problema de que al leer datos con el `fgets()` me quedaban elementos en la entrada estandar para la siguiente lectura cuando se superaba el limite de caracteres de la cadena, esto rompia el programa con mucha facilidad. Esto claro se debe a que `fgets()` solo toma los **x** elementos de la entrada que necesita (donde x es : `fgets(cadena, x, stdin)`), con lo cual si hay mas de los que necesita, estos quedaran alli. Cree una solucion, es la siguiente (ademas agregue listas doblemente enlazadas para que se vieran los elementos que quedaban en el buffer) ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_STR_LEN 5

// estructuras
typedef struct nodo {
    int element;
    struct nodo* siguiente; 
    struct nodo* anterior;
} nodo;
typedef struct lista {
    nodo *cabeza;
} lista;

// prototipos
void limpiar_buffer();
lista *crear_lista();
nodo *crear_nodo(int element);
void mostrar_lista(lista *lista);
void agregar_elemento(lista *lista,nodo *nuevo_nodo);
void vaciar_lista(lista *lista);
void eliminar_nodo(nodo *nodo_a_eliminar);


void limpiar_buffer(){
    char curr_char = getchar();
    lista *elementos_restantes = crear_lista();
    while ( curr_char != EOF && curr_char != '\n' ){
        agregar_elemento(elementos_restantes, crear_nodo(curr_char));
        curr_char = getchar();
    }
    mostrar_lista(elementos_restantes);
    vaciar_lista(elementos_restantes);
}


void eliminar_nodo(nodo *nodo_a_eliminar){
    nodo_a_eliminar->siguiente = nodo_a_eliminar->anterior =  NULL;
    free(nodo_a_eliminar);
}


void vaciar_lista(lista *lista){
    if ( lista->cabeza == NULL){
        // en caso de que no hayan elementos
        return;
    } else  if ( lista->cabeza->siguiente == NULL ){
        lista->cabeza = NULL;
    } else {
        nodo *nodo_actual = lista->cabeza;
        nodo *nodo_anterior, *nodo_eliminable;
        while ( nodo_actual->siguiente != NULL){
            nodo_anterior = nodo_actual;
            nodo_actual = nodo_actual->siguiente;
        }
        // llegamos hasta el final de la lista
        while ( nodo_anterior != NULL){
            nodo_eliminable = nodo_actual;
            nodo_anterior = nodo_anterior->anterior;
            nodo_actual = nodo_actual->anterior;
            free(nodo_eliminable);
        }
        // eliminamos todos los elementos menos la cabeza
        lista->cabeza = NULL;
    }
}

lista *crear_lista(){
    lista *nueva_lista = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));
    nueva_lista->cabeza = NULL;
    return nueva_lista;
}

nodo *crear_nodo(int element){
    nodo *nuevo_nodo= (nodo *) malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    nuevo_nodo->element = element;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = nuevo_nodo->anterior =  NULL;
    return nuevo_nodo;
}
void mostrar_lista(lista *lista){
    if ( lista->cabeza == NULL ){
        return;
    } else {
        nodo *nodo_actual = lista->cabeza;
        printf("\n Elementos que quedaron en el buffer -> [ ");
        while ( nodo_actual != NULL ){
            if ( nodo_actual->siguiente != NULL ){
                printf("%c, ", nodo_actual->element);
            } else {
                printf("%c ", nodo_actual->element);
            }
            nodo_actual = nodo_actual->siguiente;
        }
        printf(" ]\n");
    }
}
void agregar_elemento(lista *lista,nodo *nuevo_nodo){
    if ( lista->cabeza == NULL ){
        lista->cabeza = nuevo_nodo;
        lista->cabeza->siguiente = NULL;
        lista->cabeza->anterior = NULL;
    } else {
        nodo *nodo_actual = lista->cabeza; 
        nodo *nodo_anterior;
        while ( nodo_actual != NULL ){
            nodo_anterior = nodo_actual;
            nodo_actual = nodo_actual->siguiente;
        }
        nodo_anterior->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
        nodo_anterior->siguiente->anterior = nodo_anterior;
        nodo_anterior->siguiente->siguiente = NULL;
    }
}


int main(){
    char cadena[MAX_STR_LEN];
    while (1){
        printf("Introduce tu nombre completo -> ");
        fgets(cadena, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);
        printf("Tu nombre completo es %s\n", cadena);
        limpiar_buffer();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

En caso de que tenga alguna sugerencia para la mejora del codigo, soy todo oidos. El problema es que cuando no se supera el limite de caracteres al leer (`MAX_STR_LEN`), por alguna razon el programa se queda parado y tienes que darle nuevamente al `enter` para que continue ... Alguna explicacion?. Obviamente tiene algo que ver con la funcion `limpiar_buffer` es la que empleo para correr el cursor nuevamente al final de la entarda estandar ... Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lee correctamente, en `stdin` no va a quedar un `\n`, asi que tu funcion
limpiar buffer va a eliminar una linea que si era una entrada valida. Lo unico
que tienes que hacer es revisar si la lectura fue correcta usando una funcion
como esta:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool buffer_needs_cleanup(const char * const last_read) {
    const size_t len = strlen(last_read);
    // Si no leyo el '\n', se necesita limpiar el resto del buffer
    if (len && last_read[len - 1U] != '\n') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ya cuando leas haces:

```
    fgets(cadena, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);
    if (buffer_needs_cleanup(cadena)) {
        limpiar_buffer();
    }
```

Comment: Buena idea, gracias por eso :)

Comment: Por cierto en la funcion bool buffer_needs_cleanup estaria mejor comprobar si el salto de linea esta en la cadena y no en el ultimo elemento de la misma ...

Comment: `fgets` lee unicamente una linea, asi que solo habra un salto de linea y
estara al final de la cadena.

Comment: fgets no lee la linea completa, ese es gets. fgets solo toma x elementos de la entrada estandar ( fgets( cadena, x, stdin) ), entonces en caso de que el usuario ponga mas de x elementos en la entrada esa cadena no tendra un salto de linea y habra que limpiar la entrada. Sin embargo, por ejemplo en caso de que x sea 10 y el usuario meta una cadena de 5 elementos, el salto de linea estara en el 5 elemento, no al final de la cadena

Comment: El 5nto elemento seria el final de la cadena. Una cadena de caracteres es una serie de `char`s finalizados con un `'\0'`. Aunque tu buffer sea mas grande, el largo de la cadena sera hasta el `'\0'`.

Comment: Creo que ya entendí donde esta la confusión. `strlen` no te regresa el tamaño del buffer, te regresa la cantidad de caracteres de la cadena. Si tiene 5 caracteres, te retornara 5. En el ejemplo que tu me das, `strlen` retornara `6` (los 5 caracteres [0-4] y el salto de linea [5]), entonces la función revisa que el salto de linea este en la posición `5`. Como encuentra el salto de linea en la posición `5`, no se limpia el buffer, ya que se leyo bien.

Comment: Entonces cuando digo, *"estara al final de la cadena"*, no me refiero al final del buffer, sino al caracter que esta antes del el `\0`.